# Refreshing summary data quickly to minimize downtime

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

In order to increase the response time for reporting, I've created a summary table which acts like a materialized view. I haven't determined how often I will be refreshing the data because I'm still deciding how to actually swap the data out.

Updating the data based on a key isn't an option with the current structure, since each record is created from a distinct combination of many columns, some of which can be null. This causes updates to match multiple rows when null values are involved. Data is only updated in the database once or twice per day, so there's really no need to update it extremely often.

As I currently have it set up, my stored procedure simply truncates the data in the summary table and then immediately reruns the query to repopulate it from scratch. Since I'm pulling from millions of records, this can take some time. Is there a standard practice for replacing large datasets extremely quickly to minimize the downtime of the data? Something like loading the new summary data into a temporary table and then moving it to the summary table after the query finishes, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some DB kung fu I've used to good effect to work around this kind of problem: You use a simple data-driven switch to flip between current and next versions of the data.

Here's some SQL to demonstrate this in action.

Create a table somewhere to hold the switch (you could use anything here - if you have a settings table etc):

```
create table data_switch(val int not null); // this will hold one row
```

Next, alter your data table to have a column for the data version number:

```
alter table my_data add column data_version int;
```

Finally, create a view that links the two making the data_version value drive which set of data is used:

```
create view current_data as
select * from my_data
where data_version = (select val from data_switch);
```

When you generate your data, assign a new value to the data_version. When you're ready to use it, you just update the value in data_switch to match the new value you've used.

This allows you keep old versions, switch back if the new version is broken, take as long as you need to calculate the new data, truncate older versions whenever you want, and make the switch between versions instantaneous. It's simple and it works.

You can vary exactly how you implement this, but this is the general idea.